# Disable "Commands Menu" text in bottom-left of screen

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

In Final Fantasy VII Remake, on the lower left side of the screen, there is some text that says "commands menu" constantly while you're walking around. I would like to disable this so that it does not corrupt my screenshots in game. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, there are no settings to toggle that part of the display. It's always visible.